# Agendar una cita

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

tengo otro problema que no he podido resolver y quisiera de su ayuda para intentar salvarme.

El problema es el siguiente:
Debo registrar citas, en las cuales introducen la fecha de la cita usando el plug in de full calendar, después de eso, ver que horarios están disponibles en la base de datos de dicho día seleccionado. Y cuando se seleccione la hora, mostrar si en esa hora hay mas citas o solo esa. Luego de seleccionar la hora, se debe habilitar el botón de agendar y de ahí en fuera se guarda todo. Acá dejo lo que llevo hecho hasta ahora.

html

```
<div class="container text-center">
        <h2>Seleccione la fecha en la que desee su cita</h2>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Seleccione la hora de su cita</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Cita para el: </label><label id="dia" name="info" class="ml-1"></label><br>
        <label for="hora">Hora</label> <select class="form-control" name="hora" id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
                                <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled>Seleccione una hora</option>
                                <option value="09:00:00">09:00 am - 09:30 am</option>
                                <option value="09:30:00">09:30 am - 10:00 am</option>
                                <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am - 10:30 am</option>
                                <option value="10:30:00">10:30 am - 11:00 am</option>
                                <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am - 11:30 am</option>
                                <option value="11:30:00">11:30 am - 12:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm - 12:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="12:30:00">12:30 pm - 01:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="13:00:00">01:00 pm - 01:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="13:30:00">01:30 pm - 02:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="14:00:00">02:00 pm - 02:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="14:30:00">02:30 pm - 03:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="15:00:00">03:00 pm - 03:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="15:30:00">03:30 pm - 04:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="16:00:00">04:00 pm - 04:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="16:30:00">04:30 pm - 05:00 pm</option>
                                <option value="17:00:00">05:00 pm - 05:30 pm</option>
                                <option value="17:30:00">05:30 pm - 06:00 pm</option>
                            </select><br>
        <label>Disponibilidad: </label> <label id="disponibilidad" name="disponibilidad"></label>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled="" id="agendar">Agendar Cita</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js del calendar

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'es',
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next, month'
      },

      navLinks: true,
      editable: true,
      weekends: false,



      dateClick: function(info) {
        var actual = new Date();
      if(info.date >= actual){
        info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        $("#exampleModal").modal();
        document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML= info.dateStr;
      }else{
        alert("Error: No se puede solicitar una cita en una fecha vencida");
      }
}
    });

    calendar.render();
```

Js del select

```
       function changeFunc() {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

        document.getElementById('agendar').disabled=false;

       }
```

php

```
        if (isset($_POST['dia']) && !empty($_POST['dia']))
        {   
            $Fecha = strip_tags($_POST['dia']);

            $agendafechas = $this->model('buho_servicio_faq_feedback');
            $agendafecha = $agendafechas->agendafecha([
                "dia"=>$Fecha
            ]);
            if($disponible = "true"){
            $disponibilidad = "Disponible";
            }else if($disponible ="media"){
            $disponibilidad = "Disponible con un contratiempo.";
            }else {
                $disponibilidad ="Hora no disponible";
            }
        }


            $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cita WHERE ID_Proyecto=107 AND DATE(Fecha_Cita)=':Fecha' AND TIME(Fecha_Cita)BETWEEN(09:00,09:30);");
            $this->db->bind(":Fecha", $Fecha)
            $cantidad = $this->db->fetch();
            switch ($cantidad) {
                case '1':
                    # Hora disponible
                    break;
                case '2':
                    # Hora disponible con un posible retraso
                    break;
                default:
                    # Hora no disponible
                    break;
            }
```

Y no sé si está bien o si está mal... Saludos de nuevo.

Comment: pero cual es el problema?

Comment: Que no sé como mandar un AJAX desde el fullcalendar hacia el servidor